# How to do wireless installaton of Ad Hoc App on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, bundle, ad-hoc-distribution

I want to distribute IPA to testers by wireless.

I have searched and found one example.

[Example for Wireless Ad Hoc Distribution](http://gknops.github.io/adHocGenerate/)

But it did not work with me. It shows Not valid for URL.

I am using `http` url. Few links shows that it require `https` ,

Is that true ? Or I need to configure something else.

Please respond.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your ad hoc package for enterprise distribution, edit the generated HTML for the correct locations.
Note that starting from iOS 7 or 8 (not sure), the IPA and PLIST files must be located in a secured website (https).

Here is a sample without using "save for enterprise":

HTML:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://YourPlistLocation.plist">Install</a>
```

And the plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://Your IPA Location</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http://your image location</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <false/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>http:// your icon location</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.your.bundle.id.goes.here</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>YourVersionHere</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>subtitle</key>
            <string>Your subtitle here</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>Your title here</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Might be https require. Wait for others input.

Comment: _Might_? it is definitely required, but only for the actual IPA file.

Comment: One more thing, I could not find .plist Where it locate ?

Comment: @SolidSoft - either create the plist using Xcode (when saving for enterprise distribution) or use the template I added to the answer (and edit all of the "Your stuff here").

Comment: I have did some edit in URL scheme, But not generate .plist file. Could you please give me steps to generate .plist 
I am almost there to solve it.

Comment: Just copy the XML in my answer and save it as a plist file, don't forget to edit it, of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65144/discussion-between-solid-soft-and-imoses).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [diawi.com](http://diawi.com) - You need to export your IPA to Ad hoc deployment using XCode and then upload it to diawi.

Comment: This is another way, Not a solution of above query. 
That i know. But i need to do on my server. I don't want to share IPA before release on app store.

Comment: There are many services out there that do that, but they all end up doing what I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Shai How trust worthy is diawi.com?

Comment: @Scott - no idea, I've been using it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I follow this approach which i've previously answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20353911/1303176

But @Shai's answer using diwai.com is perfectly acceptable as well.

Comment: Shai 's answer is another way. Not a solution. Same as like yours iResign .. 
iMoses gives something hint to use https is essential.